# Model with a constrained list in the Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql

On the Google App Engine, I have a webapp2 model like this:

```
def Person(db.model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
    languages_spoken = db. ListProperty()
```

However, I'd like to have the languages_spoken list constrained to a list of options, say English, French, and Spanish, that can change as time goes on. With SQL this would be easy with person, language, and person_language tables (or similar) but I can't get my head round how to do it in this case, or even if it's possible. Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with this, thanks to the pointers from the two other answers:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

languages = ['English', 'French', 'Spanish']

def Person(ndb.model):
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    surname = ndb.StringProperty()
    languages_spoken = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, choices=languages)
```

Answer (score 2):

I you are starting an appengine project, use the new NDB instead of the datastore. You can use properties with arguments like: choices and validator: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

Answer (score 2):

By using the NDB, you can have the following:

```
def Person(ndb.model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
    languages_spoken = db. ListProperty(choices=['English', 'French', 'Spanish'])
```

For more information about it, take a look at [NDB Property Options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options).

However, notice that these options cannot change "on-the-fly". When a new option is supported by your application, you will need to add it in your model manually.